# Compare Excel sheets layout(only rows,column,row header and column header) of 2 different excel files using python and robot framework

Tags: python-3.x, excel, compare, robotframework, openpyxl

I want to Compare Excel sheets layout(only rows,column,row header and column header) of 2 different excel files using python and robot framework and keep the difference in separate excel file.

I have a code to compare all the cells of two sheets (different workbook) but can we restrict it to only compare :-

1)- No of rows,columns

2)- Row header text,column header text

3)- extra rows /columns/sheets if added/deleted

'''

```
  from openpyxl import load_workbook

  wb1 = load_workbook('AnnexureTemplates\Annex 8 (Large exposures).xlsx')

  wb2 = load_workbook('CycleTemplates\FinalValidated.xlsx')

for worksheet in wb1.sheetnames:
sheet1 = wb1[worksheet]
sheet2 = wb2[worksheet]

   # iterate through the rows and columns of both worksheets
   for row in range(1, sheet1.max_row + 1):
     for col in range(1, sheet1.max_column + 1):
        cell1 = sheet1.cell(row, col)
        cell2 = sheet2.cell(row, col)
        if cell1.value != cell2.value:
            print("Sheet {0} -> Row {1} Column {2} - {3} != {4}".format(worksheet, row, col, cell1.value,
                                                                        cell2.value))
```

EDIT 1-> the rows/column that contribute to structure of excel table are greyed , so the logic could be selecting the rows/column that are colored and then see if they are same or different from other excel.

For Example here is the benchmark template

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wVV1.png

Here is the template i need to check with benchmark template for difference in structure

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXBxV.png

Comment: what does robot framework have to do with this ?

Comment: using robot framework with python is a task ,i am trying to keep logic in python file and will call the py file from robot

Answer (score 0):

After so many failed attempts , I come up with this solution:-

P.S **I am new to Python so the code will not be an optimized solution, All suggestions to make it better/optimized are welcomed**

So let's says I have a Benchmark Template -> benchmark.xlsx
and the testing template -> testing template .
My approach is :-

1)-Loading both templates

2)-Getting the RGB value of the colored cells (which need to be tested) and verifying the RGB values with the hard coded RGB value .

3)-Storing the verified colored cells with data in separate dataframes for both the files.

4)-Comparing the dataframes using isin function (for nan value to be checked as well)

5)-Output the difference (if any) in DifferenceExcel.xlsx file

Code ->

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pandas as pd
df_global1 = []
df_global2 = []
def verifyRGB(expRGB, actRGB):
    exp_R, exp_G, exp_B = expRGB.split(",")
    actRGB = actRGB.replace(" ", "")
    act_R, act_G, act_B = actRGB.split(",")

    if (exp_R == act_R and exp_G == act_G and exp_B == act_B):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def getRGB(xlCell):
    C = xlCell.Interior.Color
    # print("value is ",C)
    R = C % 256
    G = C // 256 % 256
    B = C // 65536 % 256

    return "R={}, G={}, B={}".format(R, G, B)


def getDataFrame(ws):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['row', 'Column', 'Test_template_value'])
    used = ws.UsedRange
    nrows = used.Row + used.Rows.Count - 1
    ncols = used.Column + used.Columns.Count - 1

    for i in range(1, nrows):
         for j in range(1, ncols):
            cell_obj = ws.Cells(i, j)
            if (verifyRGB("R=217.0,G=217.0,B=217.0", getRGB(cell_obj))):
                dfTemp = pd.DataFrame([[i, j, cell_obj.Value]],
                                      columns=['row', 'Column',
                                               'Test_template_value'])
                df = df.append(dfTemp)
        # print("dataframe ready")
    return df


def checkDataframesDifference(df1, df2):
    df1_str_tuples = df1.astype(str).apply(tuple, 1)
    df2_str_tuples = df2.astype(str).apply(tuple, 1)
    df1_values_in_df2_filter = df1_str_tuples.isin(df2_str_tuples)
    # print("common values in both dataframes", df1_values_in_df2_filter)
    df1_values_not_in_df2 = df1[~df1_values_in_df2_filter]
    if df1_values_not_in_df2.size > 0 :
        print("Structural Difference Found :")
        print("Testing template values that are not in benchmark template:", 
     df1_values_not_in_df2)
        df1_values_not_in_df2.to_excel('DifferenceExcel.xlsx', 
index=False, header=True)
    else :
        print("No difference Found between both templates  ")
     # df1_values_not_in_df2.to_excel('./ExcelCompareOnCellColor_diff.xlsx', 
index=False, header=True)


try:
    xlApp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open ('benchmark.xlsx')
    ws1 = wb1.Worksheets('1')
    wb2 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open('testing.xlsx')
    ws2 = wb2.Worksheets('000')


df_global1 = getDataFrame(ws1)
df_global2 = getDataFrame(ws2)

checkDataframesDifference(df_global2, df_global1)

wb1.Close(False)
wb2.Close(False)
xlApp.Visible = False

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    xlApp.Quit
    ws = None
```

Again , Please suggest how can I optimize the code .

for example -> I have created too many dataframes ,how can i reduce it ?